# Cryptic compiler errors

Tags: arduino-pro-micro

I'm getting the error:

```
    left_hand:3:20: error: expected ']' before ';' token
     #define HAND_ROWS 5;
                        ^
```

on this code:

```
    #include <Keyboard.h>

    #define HAND_ROWS 5;
    #define HAND_COLS 6;
    #define ROW_PINS {9, 8, 7, 6, 5};
    #define COL_PINS {10, 16, 14, 15, 18, 19};
    #define LOOP_SPEED = 10;

    const char keymap[HAND_ROWS][HAND_COLS] = {{0xB1, '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'}, 
                                               {0xB3, 0x81, 'q', 'w', 'e', 'r'}, 
                                               {'6', 0x80, 'a', 's', 'd', 'f'}, 
                                               {'7', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b'}, 
                                               {'h', 'j', 0x82, ' ', 'k', 'l'}};
    boolean pressedKeys;
    int keymapIndex;
```

help, please? This makes no sense to me...
If I try to use Keyboard.LEFT_SHIFT and equivalent constants for the hex-codes in the keymap, they tell me 'expected unqualified-id before numerical constant'
What does this even mean? I'm so lost...

Comment: There's no semicolon needed on a #define.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mustn't terminate a `#define` with a `;`.  Semicolons are for C and C++ statements. `#define` is a *preprocessor* statement.

`#define` creates a literal string replacement, so when you use it you end up with:

```
const char keymap[5;][6;] = {...
```

which is, of course, wrong.

Comment: Thank you for catching my beginner mistake!

Comment: It's no beginner mistake... I have done it myself from time to time... the fingers go on automatic...

Comment: Guess that's the fate of Java programmers who move to C, or at least that's the case for me.

Comment: @LowellCamp Or the fate of people that jump between three or four programming languages at once - and do their programming in the wee small hours of the morning ;)